# Android Studio Kotlin Passing Intents multiple times and global array?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-developer-api

I have 3 activities:

- Home
- Add Ticket
- Ticket summary
- Add ticket issuer

At Home, it will show a ListView of all the tickets added from "Add Ticket".
When user submit details they entered in "Add Ticket" activity, they will be brought to "Ticket summary".
When user clicks on "add issuer", he will be brought to "Add ticket issuer" activity where he can add more information. After submitting, he will be brought back to "Ticket Summary" activity that shows the original data along with the new (ticket issuer) data.

When user navigates to "Home" activity, the list should be updated.

How should I do this? Is it possible to pass intent from e.g activity A to B. Then at B more information is added. Then from B back to A ?

How do I maintain that? I have the following code snippet:

```
class Ticketing: Application()     {


var ticketArray:ArrayList<Ticketing>? = null


private val ticketinstance= Ticketing()

fun getInstance():Ticketing{

    return ticketinstance
}




fun addMovie(ticket:TicketingClass){
    ticketArray?.add(ticket)
}

fun getArray():ArrayList<Tickets>?{
    return ticketArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to pass intent from e.g activity A to B. Then at B more information is added. Then from B back to A ?

While creating new Intent, you read data from previous and add previus data + current data and send it to next activity.

Comment: Which do I use?